# Unresponsive Google jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, request, google-api

I get the following dialog on load:

> #### Warning:Unresponsive script
>
> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>
> Script: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js:70
>
> `Continue |` `Debug script |` `Stop script`

### What is this happening?

Is it a common occurrence? Does it typically happen due to something in the user's code?

#### Why is the jQuery being requested on port 70`*` anyway?

---

`*` - A few minutes ago the error showed it being requested on port 71

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because there is some infinite loop (or some very hard action which can't your PC handle) in your jQuery code.

It's not port, but line. (http://address.com:port/path/to/jquery.js:line)